# Получение списка ключей из Collection или как изобрести Map

Tags: excel, vba, office, ms-access, ms-word

Collection в общем-то весьма неплох: запихнул чего нада, присвоил ключ для удобству и обращайся по нему... Но, допустим, ключи у нас динамически генерируются в зависимости от содержимого и заранее мы "not sure"(©Идиократия), чагой туда понапихивали? Тут бы и пригодился список доступных ключей, который, увы, не доступен...
Недолго гугля, наткнулся на [очередные костыли](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935108/1927236), которые оформлены в виде 1,5 класса и приведены ниже. Сразу оговорюсь: **не** идеал, всесторонне **не** тестировалось, мопед **не** мой (щютка).
Итак приступим (вознеся молитву Аллаху абы не глючило):

1. Создаём `Class Module`-хранилище спарок ключ/значение/чегонибудьещёнавыбор (`clsMapItem`):

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private key As String 'Собсно ключ, обязательно String'
   Private value As Variant 'Место для хранения, можно несколько и разных'

   'Я использовал Property как более каноничный способ записи геттеров/сеттеров'
   'Но принципиального отличия от Sub и Function нет'

   Public Property Let SetKey(sKey As String)
       key = sKey
   End Property

   Public Property Set SetValue(ByVal vValue As Variant) 'Сеттер для Object'
       Set value = vValue
   End Property

   Public Property Let LetValue(ByVal vValue As Variant) 'Для примитивов'
       value = vValue
   End Property

   Public Property Get GetKey() As String
       GetKey = key
   End Property

   Public Property Get GetObjVal() As Variant 'Геттеры для Obj и прим-ов так же раздельны'
       Set GetObjVal = value
   End Property

   Public Property Get GetPrmVal() As Variant
       GetPrmVal = value
   End Property
   ```
2. Создаём `Class Module`-реализацию `Map`-a (`clsMap`):

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private colVault As Collection 'Хранилище'
   Private mapItem As clsMapItem 'представитель из п.1'

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       Set colVault = New Collection 'Создали инстанс? Создаём хранилище'
   End Sub

   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Set colVault = Nothing 'Чистим за собой'
       Set mapItem = Nothing
   End Sub

   'Складовщик переданных няшек'
   'Если ключ есть - вынимаем слона и запихиваем жирафа (переписываем значение)'
   'Если нету ключа - подключаем новую спарку холодильник/соСлоном'
   Public Sub Store(k As String, ByVal v As Variant)
       If (Contains(k)) Then
          On Error Resume Next 'Так-как тип переданного значения неизвестен'
          Set mapItem.SetValue = v 'Пробуем оба варианта присвоения'
          mapItem.LetValue = v 'Один да проскочит обязательно'
          On Error GoTo 0 'Вот такие вот костыли =)'
       Else
          Set mapItem = New clsMapItem
          mapItem.SetKey = k
          On Error Resume Next
          Set mapItem.SetValue = v
          mapItem.LetValue = v
          On Error GoTo 0
          colVault.add mapItem, k
       End If
   End Sub

   'Проверятель присутствия ключей'
   'Странно, но факт: в VBA7 (Office 2010) функции нет, а по документам есть...'
   Public Function Contains(k As String) As Boolean
       Contains = False 'По умолчанию и так False, но мало ли...'
       On Error GoTo Skip
       Set mapItem = colVault(k)
       Contains = True
   Skip:
   End Function

   'Просто обёртка, нас тут всё устраивает'
   Public Sub Remove(k As String)
       colVault.Remove (k)
   End Sub

   'Убиватель слонов. Тоже задокументированная функция-призрак...'
   Public Sub Clear()
       Set colVault = New Collection 'Просто новое хранилище. Старое удалит мусорщик при нехватке памяти/по таймеру'
   End Sub

   'И ещё одна обёртка'
   Public Function Count() As Integer
       Count = colVault.Count
   End Function

   'Выдаватель ключей'
   Public Function GetKeys() As Collection
       Set GetKeys = New Collection
       For Each mapItem In colVault
           GetKeys.add (mapItem.GetKey)
       Next mapItem
   End Function

   'Выдаватель значений'
   Public Function GetValue(k As String) As Variant
       Set mapItem = colVault(k)
       On Error Resume Next 'Здесь костыли идентичны в Store'
       Set GetValue = mapItem.GetObjVal 'Только с геттерами'
       GetValue = mapItem.GetPrmVal
       On Error GoTo 0
   End Function
   ```
3. Нагло пользуем =)

Вот как-то так... Ваши предложения/пожелания/способы реализации `Map`-o подобного функционала?

---

Да, вот чего хотел ещё спросить: есть ли возможность написания сабкласса внутри модуля, дабы лишний раз сущностей не плодить?

Comment: Хм, а зачем в `clsMapItem` нужен `key`? Вроде ж он не используется нифига.

Comment: Используется как хранилище ключа и получения его через `clsMap.GetKeys()` (в виде коллекции всех присутствующих ключей), чего собсно и добивались от стандартного `Collection`

Comment: А, точно :) Ну вроде бы реализация правильная, хотя, конечно, странно, что `Collection` не даёт список ключей.

Comment: Для эффективности можно было бы держать отдельно список всех ключей, чтобы не пересоздавать его каждый раз. Тогда, правда, этот список придётся обновлять каждый раз на добавлении/удалении элемента, что приведёт к потере производительности, так что может быть лучше оставить как есть.

---
А в убивателе слонов вы уверены, что вы не убиваете лишь копию ссылки? В .NET переменная цикла foreach локальная, то есть присвоение ей не меняет массив. А как в VBA?

---
А в начале `Contains` не надо `Contains = false`?

Comment: Насчёт убивателя не уверен, в VBA толком не освоился... Сейчас пишу койчего с использованием Map и параллельно проверяю на баги/фичи =) 
Первоначально было  просто `Set colVault = New Collection`, возможно стоит вернуть.
______  
`Contains` по умолчанию принимает `False`, хотя... бережоного код меньше гючит XD

Comment: foreach таки локален, упрощаем убиватель слонов... а заодно `Object` меняем на `Variant` ибо генерик.

Comment: А вот незнаю универсального способа присвоения примитивов и объектов, пришлось костыли мудрить... Да, для экономии памяти думаю можно в `Store` ставить `ByRef`, копия по идее создаётся в сеттере `clsMapItem`?

Comment: элемент можно было объявить проще - просто публичные члены-данные, без всяких там геттеров/сеттеров.

для выбора Let/Set есть функция IsObject - механизм обработки ошибок работает медленнее, чем прямая проверка. 

по поводу убивателя: VBA - это COM, так что никаких проблем с памятью, она будет освобождаться сразу же. 

ну и добавлю еще, что реализация коллекций в VBA медленная - при тысячах объектов в коллекции оно очень существенно тормозит. если хотите быстро - реализуете упорядоченное самобалансирующееся дерево (тот же АВЛ вполне подойдет).

Answer (score 0):

Тоже писал подобный костыль, с применением похожего подхода, правда в одном класс-модуле. Сперва пытался комментировать в ключевых местах... Но потом забил. Я не профессиональный программист, и API VBA знаю так себе, так что код достаточно простой. Думаю будет и так понятно.

Нужно создать `ClassModule` (у меня он называется `AssocArray.cls`) и вставить следующий код:

```
Private mainarr() As Variant ' главный массив хранения данных
Private count_mainarr As Integer ' длинна словаря

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    count_mainarr = 0
End Sub

Public Sub Add(Key, Value) 'добавление пары Ключ/Значение
    If Not KeyIn(Key) Then ' если ключа нет, то добавляется пара полностью
        ReDim Preserve mainarr(count_mainarr)
        mainarr(count_mainarr) = Array(Key, Value)
        count_mainarr = count_mainarr + 1
    Else ' если ключ есть, то значение добавляется к существующему
        numkey = GetKeyNum(Key)
        Dim new_value()

        If IsArray(mainarr(numkey)(1)) Then ' если значение по ключу - массив
            If IsArray(Value) Then ' если переданное значение так же массив
                If IsObject(mainarr(numkey)(1)) Then
                    Set old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                Else
                    old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                End If
                newcount = UBound(old_value) + UBound(Value) - LBound(old_value) - LBound(Value) ' вычисление нового значения длинны словаря
                ReDim new_value(newcount)
                step = 0
                For i = LBound(old_value) To UBound(old_value)
                    If IsObject(old_value(i)) Then
                        Set new_value(step) = old_value(i)
                    Else
                        new_value(step) = old_value(i)
                    End If
                    step = step + 1
                Next i
                For i = LBound(Value) To UBound(Value)
                    If IsObject(Value(i)) Then
                        Set new_value(step) = Value(i)
                    Else
                        new_value(step) = Value(i)
                    End If
                    step = step + 1
                Next i
                mainarr(numkey)(1) = new_value
            Else
                If IsObject(mainarr(numkey)(1)) Then
                    Set old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                Else
                    old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                End If
                newcount = UBound(old_value) - LBound(old_value) + 1
                ReDim new_value(newcount)
                For i = 0 To newcount - 1
                    If IsObject(old_value(i)) Then
                        Set new_value(i) = old_value(i)
                    Else
                        new_value(i) = old_value(i)
                    End If
                Next i
                If IsObject(Value) Then
                    Set new_value(newcount) = Value
                Else
                    new_value(newcount) = Value
                End If
                mainarr(numkey)(1) = new_value
            End If
        Else
            If IsArray(Value) Then
                If IsObject(mainarr(numkey)(1)) Then
                    Set old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                Else
                    old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                End If
                ReDim new_value(0)
                If IsObject(old_value) Then
                    Set new_value(0) = old_value
                Else
                    new_value(0) = old_value
                End If
                d = LBound(Value) - 1
                For i = 1 To (UBound(Value) + 1 - LBound(Value))
                    ReDim Preserve new_value(i)
                    If IsObject(Value(i + d)) Then
                        Set new_value(i) = Value(i + d)
                    Else
                        new_value(i) = Value(i + d)
                    End If
                Next i
                mainarr(numkey)(1) = new_value
            Else
                If IsObject(Value) Then
                    Set old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                Else
                    old_value = mainarr(numkey)(1)
                End If
                ReDim new_value(1)
                If IsObject(old_value) Then
                    Set new_value(0) = old_value
                Else
                    new_value(0) = old_value
                End If
                If IsObject(Value) Then
                    Set new_value(1) = Value
                Else
                    new_value(1) = Value
                End If
                mainarr(numkey)(1) = new_value
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetValue(Key)
    If KeyIn(Key) Then
        If IsObject(mainarr(GetKeyNum(Key))(1)) Then
            Set GetValue = mainarr(GetKeyNum(Key))(1)
        Else
            GetValue = mainarr(GetKeyNum(Key))(1)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Ключ `" & Key & "` в словаре не обнаружен!"
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetKeys()
    Dim res(), res_count As Integer
    If count_mainarr > 0 Then
        For i = LBound(mainarr) To UBound(mainarr)
            ReDim Preserve res(res_count)
            res(res_count) = mainarr(i)(0)
            res_count = res_count + 1
        Next i
    End If
    GetKeys = res
End Function

Public Function KeyIn(Key) As Boolean
    KeyIn = False
    If count_mainarr > 0 Then
        For Each k In GetKeys()
            If k = Key Then
                KeyIn = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next k
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetKeyNum(Key) As Integer
    Dim num As Integer
    GetKeyNum = -1
    If count_mainarr > 0 Then
        num = LBound(mainarr)
        For Each k In GetKeys()
            If k = Key Then
                 GetKeyNum = num
                 Exit Function
            End If
            num = num + 1
        Next k
    End If
End Function

Property Get Count() As Integer
    Count = count_mainarr
End Property

Property Get TypeObj() As String
    TypeObj = "AssocArray"
End Property
```

Данным классом успешно пользуюсь в достаточно объемных скриптах уже третий год. Пока ошибок и критических провисаний в производительности не замечено.

---

На сколько я знаю, VBA - язык объектный (в той части, что оперирует объектами и позволяет создавать классы ограниченной функциональности), но не реализующий полную парадигму ООП, так что такие вещи, как наследование и саб-классы здесь невозможны.